# Wide to long on subset of columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to turn a number of columns to long format (wide to long). I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46478510/reshape-pandas-dataframe-wide-to-long-with-some-variables-to-stack-other-varia) and I didn't seem to get it right. How can I get this right by pivoting the "London, New York, Boston" columns to long format?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date' : ['2021-08-01', '2021-08-01', '2021-08-01', '2021-08-02', '2021-08-02', '2021-08-02'],
    'person': ['type_A', 'type_C', 'type_C', 'type_A', 'type_B', 'type_D'],
    'London' : [1, 4, 7, 5, 7, 9],
    'New York' : [2, 5, 8, 7, 9, 10],
    'Boston' : [3, 6, 9, 1, 2, 7]
})
df['id'] = df.index
pd.wide_to_long(df, ["place"], i="id", j="value")
```

Comment: Do you mean by? `df.melt(['date', 'person'])`

Comment: How looks expected ouput? Maybe need [`melt`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28654047) - `df.melt(['date','person'])`

Comment: Thank you! Yes, actually `melt()` works better in this case!