# How to create duplicate rows based on columns?

Tags: python, data-cleaning

Consider this data frame

```
order number | Item               | column 0 | column 1 | Column 2 
12           | [abcd][efgh]       | [abcd    | [efgh]   |     
34           | [mnop] |           | [mnop]   |          | 
56           | [xyzz][zzyx][mnoq] | [xyzz]   | [zzyx]   | [mnoq]
```

How do I turn it into?

```
order number | Item               | column 0 |  
12           | [abcd][efgh]       | [abcd    |     
12           | [abcd][efgh]       | [efgh]   |   
34           | [mnop] |           | [mnop]   |    
56           | [xyzz][zzyx][mnoq] | [xyzz]   |
56           | [xyzz][zzyx][mnoq] | [zzyx]   |   
56           | [xyzz][zzyx][mnoq] | [mnoq]   |
```

This is my first time posting on stackoverflow so apologies for any mistakes. I've tried searching the blogs but have not any luck with this kind of problem. Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten multiple columns in a dataframe to a single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46435329/flatten-multiple-columns-in-a-dataframe-to-a-single-column)