# Concatenate all columns of a pandas DataFrame into the first one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a dataframe with N (>10000) columns, and I want to concatenate all of them into the first column (in other words, one "below" the other, all in the first column).

What I have looks like this:

```
cols = {'col1':['a','a','b','b'], ... , 'coln':[1,2,3,4]}
a = pd.DataFrame(cols)
a

   col1 ... coln
    0   ...   1
    4   ...   2
    3   ...   3
    3   ...   4
```

And I am trying to get something like this:

```
col1    
 0  
 4 
 3  
 3  
...
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

Normally I would do something like this, which actually works:

```
b = pd.concat([a['col1'], ..., a['coln']]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

But I am wondering if there is a better way to do it, since for a big dataframe my approach will take a long time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46435329/flatten-multiple-columns-in-a-dataframe-to-a-single-column), but to summarize:

```py
b = pd.concat([a[col] for col in a])
```

Comment: I thought someone already asked for this, but didn't find it. Thanks